# Doubt in differentiation in replacing terms

Tags: calculus

Let's say we have $y=f(x^3)$ now taking derivatives both sides gives us
$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{df(x^3)}{dx^3} \times 3x^2$.

Now I am given $f'(X)=\tan x$.

So I'm taking this as $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\tan x$.

Now I was reading from a book and the book replaces the term $\dfrac{df(x^3)}{dx^3}$ with $\tan^3x$.

Now how can you do that $\dfrac{d(f(X))^3}{dx^3} = \tan^3x$.

Now aren't these different tell me where have I gone wrong. An excerpt:

> **Example 54** If $y=f(x^3)$, $z=g(x^5)$, $f^\prime(x)=\tan x$ and $g^\prime(x)=\sec x$, then find the value of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{dy/dz}{x}$.
>
> **Sol.** Here, $y=f(x^3)\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=f^\prime(x^3)\cdot3x^2$

Comment: "book replaces the term $\frac{df(x^3)}{dx^3}$ with $\tan^3 x$." ? Where? There's no mention of anything like that in the picture.

Comment: Also, be careful with the powers. $f(x^3) \neq (f(x))^3$ ; so if $f'(x) = \tan x$, that means that $f'(x^3) = \tan x^3$, not $\tan^3 x$

Comment: @Matti P. If I have equation df(x)/dx=tanx can I replace X with x^3 is that allowed

Comment: @postmortes I have applied chain rule

Comment: Be careful with the notation, also. Instead of $x \to x^3$ , I would recommend something like $x \to t^3$. This is to avoid confusion between the different $x$'s. But to answer your question, I think you have already answered it yourself in the first line of your post. If you want to change the innermost variable, you have to introduce a new derivative term, like you have written yourself.

Comment: Mate chain rule states that if y=f(g(X)) dy/dx = df(g(x))/d(g(X)×dg(X)/dx

Comment: @Matti P. I'm sorry I don't understand what u have written. Could you explain it in easier terms

Comment: Mate if u understand the above line then g(X)=x^3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109779/discussion-between-blacksusanoo-and-matti-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=f(x^3)$, so by the chain rule, $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2f'(x^3)$. You're given that $f'(x)=\tan x$, which means $f'(x^3)=\tan(x^3)$, and not $\tan^3x=(\tan x)^3$.

By applying the chain rule again,

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dz}&=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}\\[1ex]&=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dz}{dx}}\\[1ex]&=\frac{\frac{df(x^3)}{dx}}{\frac{dg(x^5)}{dx}}\\[1ex]&=\frac{3x^2f'(x^3)}{5x^4g'(x^5)}\end{align}$$

Substitute $f'(x)=\tan x$ and $g'(x)=\sec x$:

$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{3x^2\tan(x^3)}{5x^4\sec(x^5)}$$

Finally,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{dy}{dz}}x&=\frac35\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\tan(x^3)}{x^5\sec(x^5)}\\[1ex]&=\frac35\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x^5)}{\cos(x^3)}=\boxed{\frac35}\end{align}$$